# Can't connect to Oracle using tns

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracle-sqldeveloper, tnsnames, tns

I'm using an Oracle 11g R2 database. I use Oracle SQL Developer. If i create a new connection and check Basic Connection Type and fill the fields i can connect. If i select TNS and select the one i want in the dropdown menu, it says Failure E/S Exception: The Network Adapter could not establish the connection.

This is the tnsnames.ora. I use it to connect to 2 database, dblilly and astrea.
I can connect correctly to astrea. Listener is on  and the instances ready. Do you see something i miss? Do you need more info to help me?

```
# tnsnames.ora Network Configuration File: C:\OracleODAC\x32\network\admin\tnsnames.ora
# Generated by Oracle configuration tools.

LIDA_ALC_DBLILLY=
  (DESCRIPTION=
    (ADDRESS=
      (PROTOCOL=TCP)
      (HOST=192.168.109.107)
      (PORT=1521)
    )
    (CONNECT_DATA=
      (SERVER=dedicated)
      (SERVICE_NAME=orcl)
    )
  )

LIDA_INDY_DBLILLY=
  (DESCRIPTION=
    (ADDRESS=
      (PROTOCOL=TCP)
      (HOST=192.168.109.107)
      (PORT=1521)
    )
    (CONNECT_DATA=
      (SERVER=dedicated)
      (SERVICE_NAME=orcl2)
    )
  )

HARVEST_DBLILLY=
  (DESCRIPTION=
    (ADDRESS=
      (PROTOCOL=TCP)
      (HOST=192.168.109.107)
      (PORT=1521)
    )
    (CONNECT_DATA=
      (SERVER=dedicated)
      (SERVICE_NAME=orcl2)
    )
  )

DELTA_DBLILLY=
  (DESCRIPTION=
    (ADDRESS=
      (PROTOCOL=TCP)
      (HOST=192.168.109.107)
      (PORT=1521)
    )
    (CONNECT_DATA=
      (SERVER=dedicated)
      (SERVICE_NAME=orcl2)
    )
  )

AUTOLAB_DBLILLY=
  (DESCRIPTION_LIST=
    (DESCRIPTION=
      (ADDRESS=
        (PROTOCOL=TCP)
        (HOST=192.168.109.107)
        (PORT=1521)
      )
      (CONNECT_DATA=
        (SERVER=dedicated)
        (SERVICE_NAME=orcl2)
      )
    )
    (DESCRIPTION=
      (ADDRESS=
        (PROTOCOL=TCP)
        (HOST=192.168.109.107)
        (PORT=1521)
      )
      (CONNECT_DATA=
        (SERVER=dedicated)
        (SERVICE_NAME=orcl2)
      )
    )
    (DESCRIPTION=
      (ADDRESS=
        (PROTOCOL=TCP)
        (HOST=192.168.109.103)
        (PORT=1521)
      )
      (CONNECT_DATA=
        (SERVER=dedicated)
        (SERVICE_NAME=orcl.cartif.local)
      )
    )
  )

LIDA_INDY_ASTREA=
  (DESCRIPTION=
    (ADDRESS=
      (PROTOCOL=TCP)
      (HOST=192.168.109.103)
      (PORT=1521)
    )
    (CONNECT_DATA=
      (SERVER=dedicated)
      (SERVICE_NAME=orcl.cartif.local)
    )
  )

HARVEST_ASTREA=
  (DESCRIPTION=
    (ADDRESS=
      (PROTOCOL=TCP)
      (HOST=192.168.109.103)
      (PORT=1521)
    )
    (CONNECT_DATA=
      (SERVER=dedicated)
      (SERVICE_NAME=orcl.cartif.local)
    )
  )

DELTA_ASTREA=
  (DESCRIPTION=
    (ADDRESS=
      (PROTOCOL=TCP)
      (HOST=192.168.109.103)
      (PORT=1521)
    )
    (CONNECT_DATA=
      (SERVER=dedicated)
      (SERVICE_NAME=orcl.cartif.local)
    )
  )

AUTOLAB_ASTREA=
  (DESCRIPTION_LIST=
    (DESCRIPTION=
      (ADDRESS=
        (PROTOCOL=TCP)
        (HOST=192.168.109.103)
        (PORT=1521)
      )
      (CONNECT_DATA=
        (SERVER=dedicated)
        (SERVICE_NAME=orcl.cartif.local)
      )
    )
    (DESCRIPTION=
      (ADDRESS=
        (PROTOCOL=TCP)
        (HOST=192.168.109.103)
        (PORT=1521)
      )
      (CONNECT_DATA=
        (SERVER=dedicated)
        (SERVICE_NAME=orcl.cartif.local)
      )
    )
  )
```

```
# listener.ora Network Configuration File: /u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/dbhome_1/network/admin/listener.ora
# Generated by Oracle configuration tools.

SID_LIST_LISTENER =
  (SID_LIST =
    (SID_DESC =
      (SID_NAME = orcl2
      (ORACLE_HOME = /u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/dbhome_1)
      (PROGRAM = extproc)
      (ENVS = "EXTPROC_DLLS=ONLY:/u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/dbhome_1/bin/oraclr11.dll")
    )
  )

LISTENER =
  (DESCRIPTION_LIST =
    (DESCRIPTION =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = IPC)(KEY = EXTPROC1521))
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = dblilly)(PORT = 1521))
    )
  )

ADR_BASE_LISTENER = /u01/app/oracle
```

lsnrctl status

```
oracle@dblilly:/root> lsnrctl status LISTENER                                   
LSNRCTL for Linux: Version 11.2.0.1.0 - Production on 24-AUG-2015 14:57:02

Copyright (c) 1991, 2009, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

Connecting to (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=IPC)(KEY=EXTPROC1521)))
STATUS of the LISTENER
------------------------
Alias                     LISTENER
Version                   TNSLSNR for Linux: Version 11.2.0.1.0 - Production
Start Date                24-AUG-2015 12:49:04
Uptime                    0 days 2 hr. 7 min. 58 sec
Trace Level               off
Security                  ON: Local OS Authentication
SNMP                      OFF
Listener Parameter File   /u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/dbhome_1/network/admin/listener.ora
Listener Log File         /u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/dbhome_1/network/log/listener.log
Listening Endpoints Summary...
  (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=ipc)(KEY=EXTPROC1521)))
  (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=dblilly)(PORT=1521)))
Services Summary...
Service "orcl2" has 1 instance(s).
  Instance "orcl2", status READY, has 1 handler(s) for this service...
 (ORACLE_HOME = /u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/dbhome_1" has 1 instance(s).
 (ORACLE_HOME = /u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/dbhome_1", status UNKNOWN, has 1 handler(s) for this service...
Service "orcl2XDB" has 1 instance(s).
  Instance "orcl2", status READY, has 1 handler(s) for this service...
The command completed successfully
```

I can connect with this settings:

[image: I can connect with this settings]

But can't with this ones

[image: I can't connect]

Comment: Can you test the connection information from SQL Developer, not using Tnsnames?

Comment: It's the information in tnsnames, dblilly, 1521 and orcl2

Comment: I need help, or some tips to resolve the problem.

Comment: I didn't understand your last comment.  You are able to successfully connect in SQL Developer, without using tnsnames ?

Comment: Yes, but i can't using tnsnames. I'm able to connect using a connectionstring not the tnsnames.

Comment: Can you add a screenshot of your working SQL Developer connection?

Comment: @Nick I uploaded the screenshots.

Answer (score 0):

In your listener.ora, you are missing a closing `"` and a closing `)` around the ENVS parameter.

Your TNSNames file is setup to use a Service, however in SQL Developer you are connecting via the SID.  You should also change your TNSNames to specify the SID instead of the service name.

[SID vs Service Name](http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_oracle_sid_instance_name_service_name.htm)

Comment: It's not missed, it doesn't shown in nano due to terminal size. Edited.

Comment: Thanks Nick, but what can i do to use the service_name as i do with the database astrea (_astrea). The 2 database are freshly installed with the same setup, but i can use the service_name only in astrea, not in dblilly.